# AWS Transfer for SFTP - Custom Identity Provider

Tags: amazon-web-services, sftp

I'm looking into how to implement AWS Transfer for SFTP with a Custom Identity Provider.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/transfer/latest/userguide/authenticating-users.html

From what I can understand it looks like if you are going to use a custom identity provider you must authenticate using a username and password.

i.e. Custom identity provider can not be used in conjunction with SFTP keys.

Is that right?

I hope this is not a silly question. Thanks in advance

Comment: API gateway should return public keys in case of successful auth. These will be used as SFTP public keys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically when you use Custom Identity Provider and once you're authenticated, you'll allowed to assume the role and access the home directory, however you can use Lambda integration with API gateway and send the SSH public key in the Lambda generated response.